# c++ weird error with decimal to binary converter

Tags: c++

I'm a complete newbie to C++ programming. I've been given the task to code decimal to hexadecimal,octal,binary conversion.I have encountered errors in the "binario" function, when I enter a decimal number greater than 1000 the function gives me a result as a nonsense random numbers.

```
int binario(int n){
    int r,val=0, i=1;
    while (n>0) {
      val=val+(n%2*i);
      n=n/2;
      i=i*10;
   }
   return val;
}
```

Comment: Bases change the way a number is _written_, they don't change its value at all. Converting an integer to the value that _if printed in base 10_ would look like the original value in base 2 is ... really weird. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Computers only store numbers as binary. Conversion to output is handled by creating a string representation of the number in the format you want. Returning it as an int doesn't help, since you can't use it for calculation. You also can't represent hexadecimal numbers this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, the maximum size for int is 4 bytes which means from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Binary of 1024 is 10000000000 and it's more than int range. This is why you see the error. You can use your function for numbers less than 1024. I suggest you using string for your function(you have to include string header):

```
string binario(int n){
    string bin = "";
    while (n>0) {
      bin += to_string(n%2);
      n=n/2;
   }
   //reverse string
   for (int i = 0; i < bin.size() / 2; i++) {
    swap(bin[i], bin[bin.size() - i - 1]); 
   } 

   return bin;
}
```